# Server 2012 - How to change the connection folder name - RemoteApp and Desktop Connections

Tags: windows-server-2012, remoteapp

We have a terminal server 2012 with all the application installed. It works fine for all the users through RDP and also through rdweb access.

Now if I am setting up RemoteApp and Desktop Connection for users on desktop I need to change the folder name of connection as below.

Need ti change Name from Auckland BIM Cloud 2 to Auckland Cloud.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it takes the name of your RD Web Access portal. If you change it there, it should be reflected in the Start Menu.

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-RDWorkspace

Set-RDWorkspace -Name "CompanyName Resources"
```